# how do i find the derivative of this?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Consider $h(t) = (t + 4)^{2/3}(2t^2−5)^3$.

I tried using the chain and product rule and got $2/3(t+4)^{-1/3}(2t^2)+3(2t^2-5)^2(4t)$.

Greatly appreciated if someone could help explain the process.

Comment: You arenvt applying the product rue properly.  It should be $2/3 (t+4)^{-1/3}(2t^2-5)^3 +(t+4)^{2/3}*3 (2t^2-5)*4t $

Comment: h (t)=f (g (t))j (k (t)) so h'(t)=[f (g (t))]'*j (k (t)) + f (g(t))[j (k (t)l]' by the product rule. By th chain rule we get f'(g(t))g'(t)*j (k (t))+f (g (t))*j'(k (t))k'(t)

Comment: $(t+4)'=1; [(t+4)^{2/3}]'=2/3 (t+4)^{-1/3}*1; (2t^2-5)'=4t; [(2t^2-5)^3]'=3 (2t^2-5)^2*4t=12t (2t^2-5)^2.  [fg]'=f'g+fg'.  So...

Answer (score 0):

When you face expressions which contains powers, products and quotients, logarithmic differentiation make life much easier.

Considering $$h = (t + 4)^{2/3}(2t^2−5)^3$$ $$\log(h)=\frac 23 \log(t+4)+3\log(2t^2-5)$$ Differentiating $$\frac {h'}h=\frac 23\times\frac 1 {t+4}+3\times\frac {4t}{2t^2-5}=\frac{ 40 t^2+144 t-10}{3 (t+4) \left(2 t^2-5\right) }$$ How, use $$h'=h\times \frac{h'}h$$ and simplify the powers.

This should give a very compact expression for $h'$.